# Writing Chapter Prefix for Chapter entries in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I am looking for the code that allow me to append prefix "Chapter" to Chapter Entries only not for the front matter like Abstract, Declaration and also not for the Bibliography and appendices. 
Here below what I am looking for. I do not want Chapter to be printed before Candidate's Declaration, Abstract, Acknowledgment, LOF, LOT, List of abbreviations. I need it to be printed before Chapters only.

Here is what I used

```
\makeatletter

% Per-section appendicies
\newcounter{Appx}
\numberwithin{Appx}{chapter}
\def\@Appx[#1]#2{
\refstepcounter{Appx}
\section*{%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname\ \Alph{Appx}\quad#1}%
\appendixname\ \Alph{Appx}\quad#2}
}
\def\@@Appx#1{\@Appx[#1]{#1}}
\def\Appx{\@ifnextchar[\@Appx\@@Appx}

% "Chapter" prefix in ToC
\let\@@l@chapter\l@chapter
\def\l@chapter#1{\@@l@chapter{\chaptername\ #1}}

\makeatother
```

[image: Table of Contents]

Comment: Please post not only a code snippet but a Minimum Working Example (MWE, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that gives rise to the issue you're looking to fix. From the screenshot it would appear to be the case that you've customized the table of contents layout considerably -- in addition to providing an instruction that inserts "Chapter " before numbered and unnumbered "chapters". A solution to the "Chapter " business for unnumbered chapter-level entities will probably interact (interfere?!) with your other code, so it's important to know what you've done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `titlese/titletoc`you can do it. To mimick the formatting shown in your question, I had to load the `etoolbox` package in order not to include the table of contents in itself. As it seems to be rather complex to patch the `abstract` environment, I suggest you turn it into a `\chapter*` command. I supposed you were using the `report` class, which has no `\front/mainmatter` commands, so I provided them, to have roman numbering  for \frontmatter — actually, I used `small caps` roman numbering (an old tradition in French typography), but that's easy to change if you don't like it.

```
    \documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage{heuristica}
    \usepackage{microtype}

    \usepackage[pagestyles, explicit]{titlesec}%
    \usepackage{titletoc}%

    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \newbool{addtoc}%initial value:  false
    \pretocmd{\lsstyle}{\SetTracking[no ligatures = {f}]{encoding = *}{50}}{}{}%

    \titleformat{name = \chapter}[display]%
    {\lsstyle\bfseries\Large\filcenter\vskip-4\baselineskip}
    {\LARGE\chaptername~\thechapter}
    {0.5pc}
    {\vspace{0.5pc}\Huge#1}%
    \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{3\baselineskip}{8\baselineskip}

    \titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[display]
    {\vskip-4\baselineskip\lsstyle\bfseries\itshape\large\filcenter}
    {}
    {0.5pc}
    {\vspace{0.5pc}#1}%
    [\ifbool{addtoc}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}]%
     \titlespacing{name = \chapter, numberless}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{8\baselineskip}

      \titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\lsstyle\smallskip\bfseries}%\vspace{1cm}%
      {\contentslabel[\chaptername~\thecontentslabel]{0em}\hspace{5.6em}}%
      {\renewcommand\thecontentslabel{\relax}\itshape}%numberless%
      {\hfill\contentspage}[\medskip]%
    %
     \titlecontents{section}[4.25em]{\smallskip}%
      {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2em}}%numbered
      {\hspace*{-1em}}%numberless
      {\hfill\contentspage}[\smallskip]%
    %
     \titlecontents{subsection}[7em]{}%
      {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.75em}}%numbered
      {\hspace*{-1em}}%numberless
      {\hfill\contentspage}[\smallskip]

    \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\upshape TABLE OF CONTENTS \vspace{3\baselineskip}\par \hrule height 1pt\vskip1.5ex Contents\hfill Page No \vskip 1.5ex\par\hrule height 1pt\vskip -8\baselineskip}%
    \apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\booltrue{addtoc}}{}{}

    \providecommand\frontmatter{\renewcommand\thepage{\scshape\mdseries\roman{page}}}%
    \providecommand\mainmatter{\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}}

    \begin{document}

    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents

     \chapter*{Candidate’s Declaration}
     \chapter*{Abstract}
    \chapter*{Acknowledgments}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \chapter*{List of Abbreviations}

    \mainmatter

    \chapter{INTRODUCTION}

    \section{Motivation}
    \section{Introduction to Data Mining}
    \newpage

    \section{Steps for Knowledge Discovery in Databases Process}
    \section{Architecture of Data Mining System}
    \newpage

    \section{Datamining Techniques}
    \newpage

    \section{Classification}
    \subsection{Naive Bayes}
    \subsection{J48}
    \newpage

    \subsection{OneR}
    \subsection{ZeroR}
    \subsection{IBk (k nearest neighbor)}
    \section{Association Techniques}
    \section{Description of Heart disease dataset used in Experiment}

    \end{document}
```

[image]