# Adding "Chapter" before the chapter entries in the ToC causes many conflicts

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I am trying to add "Chapter" before the chapter number in the ToC.

The code I am using is

```latex
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@chapter
  {\numberline {\thechapter }}
  {\@chapapp~ \numberline {\thechapter }}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

However, it causes many conflicts with other parts in the `.cls` file. For example,

```
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\t@cfill}{\cleaders\hbox{$\m@th \mkern\@dotsep mu . \mkern\@dotsep mu$}\hfill}
\newcommand{\abbrl@bel}[1]{\makebox[\labelwidth][l]{\textbf{#1}\ \t@cfill}}
\newenvironment{mclistof}[2]{%
   \chapter*{#1}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
   \begin{list}{}%
   {\renewcommand{\makelabel}{\abbrl@bel}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{#2}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \markboth{#1}{#1}%
   }}
   {\end{list}\mtcaddchapter}
```

```
\newenvironment{alwayssingle}{%
       \@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
       \else\newpage\fi}
       {\if@restonecol\twocolumn\else\newpage\fi}
\newcommand{\@acknowledgementstitle}{Acknowledgements}

\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{
\cleardoublepage
\begin{alwayssingle}
% \setsinglecolumn
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}
}
{\end{alwayssingle}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@chapter
  {\numberline {\thechapter }}
  {\@chapapp~ \numberline {\thechapter }}
  {}{}
\makeatother


\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\t@cfill}{\cleaders\hbox{$\m@th \mkern\@dotsep mu . \mkern\@dotsep mu$}\hfill}
\newcommand{\abbrl@bel}[1]{\makebox[\labelwidth][l]{\textbf{#1}\ \t@cfill}}
\newenvironment{mclistof}[2]{%
   \chapter*{#1}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
   \begin{list}{}%
   {\renewcommand{\makelabel}{\abbrl@bel}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{#2}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \markboth{#1}{#1}%
   }}
   {\end{list}\mtcaddchapter}

\newenvironment{alwayssingle}{%
       \@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
       \else\newpage\fi}
       {\if@restonecol\twocolumn\else\newpage\fi}

\newcommand{\@acknowledgementstitle}{Acknowledgements}

\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{
\cleardoublepage
\begin{alwayssingle}
% \setsinglecolumn
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}
}
{\end{alwayssingle}}


\usepackage{blindtext}% Dummy text for the example
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you think of doing that with one of the dedicated packages (`etoc`, `titletoc`, `tocloft`)?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. I tried `tocloft`, but the word "Chaper" is overlapped with the chapter title by using `\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }`. Do you know how to deal with it?

Comment: The are width parameters to change, I guess. Personally, I tend to use `titletoc`, which comes with package `titlesec`.

Comment: @Bernard Could you point me the link of the usage of `titletoc` which do this work? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The possibilities are detailed in § 6 of titlesec documentation, (`Contents: The titletoc package`, pp. 13–19).

Comment: You might get some ideas from this: [Writing Chapter Prefix for Chapter entries in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176212/579)

Answer (score 3):

With the `tocloft` package:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter } % put Chapter before the number
% Now make extra space for the word
\newlength{\mylen} % a "scratch" length, choose any name you like
\settowidth{\mylen}{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum} % extra space
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\mylen} % add the extra space
```

Further details are in the package documentation (`> texdoc tocloft`).

Comment: Thanks. Surprisingly, this has a side effect that the "table of contents" does not starts in the odd pages and also the next. Do you know how to deal with this?

Comment: I solve it by adding `titles` option. `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`